# Android WorkManager daily task

Tags: java, android, task

How can i run a task once a day using WorkManager?
I've been trying to do this but i wasted my whole day.
Any example? for example showing a notification everyday!
(I know how to show notification but my problem is doing it daily.)

Comment: You can use AlarmManager and BroadcastReciever. Set the time and repetition interval of alarm and use pending intent to broadcast the message and show notification onRecieve method of Broadcast. Check out this blog for more details - https://www.journaldev.com/27681/android-alarmmanager-broadcast-receiver-and-service

Comment: Not the use case for WorkManager, more like AlarmManager.